# ActionLayout not showing, only its title is visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add EditText to action bar in my app, but that item isn't visible - only its  title. I know it happens when there's not enough room on the action bar, but I don't know why it is - screen definitely isn't too small, there is no more items, I also tried changing values of layout height and width but nothing works.
Here's my item in menu.xml:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/Title"
    android:title="Title"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/action_bar"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

And here's action_bar.xml layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTitle
    android:hint="Title"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="right"
    />
```

Comment: see this tutorial this may help you http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Comment: thanks, but it produces some null pointer exceptions, moreover I rather want to find out what's wrong with my method

Comment: Are you using ActionBar or Toolbar?

Answer (score 7):

I already know the answer, instead of `android:actionLayout` I should have written `app:actionLayout,` first case won't work properly with AppCompat